# How do I solve the system $x^{x+y} = y^4$ and $y^{x + y} = x$ over the integers without guessing?

Tags: number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

I have no idea how to deal with exponential functions like this. I tried guess and check for $x,y = \pm 1$, finding that $$(x, y) = (1, 1), (1, -1)$$ works. I then tried $x = \pm 2, y = \pm 4$ and $x = \pm 4, y = \pm 2$. I find the solution $$(x, y) = (4, -2)$$ I then wrote a program in python, and these are the only 3 solutions for $-10 \leq x, y \leq 10$

**Question 1:** How would I solve this system without guessing?

**Question 2:** Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Raise both sides of the RHS to the power of $(x+y)$. What can you deduce?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System of Exponential Equations in $x$ and $y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146011/system-of-exponential-equations-in-x-and-y) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E%7Bx%2By%7D%3Dy%5E4%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24y%5E%7Bx%2By%7D%3Dx%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1). Note that [solutions to $x^{x+y} = y^4, y^{x+y} = x$ in integers](/q/1320636) is also a duplicate. Other similar questions include the AoPS thread [Special equations](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1427413p8041649).

Answer (score -1):

$$x^{x+y}=y^4$$
$$y^{x+y}=x$$

Taking the logarithm both sides,

$$(x+y)\log x =4 \log y $$
$$(x+y)\log y = \log x$$

Substituting [2] into [1],

$$(x+y)(x+y)\log y =4 \log y $$

Cancelling out $\log y$ from both sides,

$$(x + y)^2 = 4 \implies x + y = \pm 2$$

By inspection, since $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$, the only integer solutions are:

$$x=1, y=1$$
$$x=4, y=-2$$
$$x=-4, y=2$$

---

1. $x=-4, y=2$ does not satisfy the original equation.

$$(-4)^{-2} = \frac{1}{16}, 2^{-2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

2. The only other solution $x=1, y=-1$ seems to be a happy coincidence, since:

$$(1)^0 = (-1)^4$$
$$(-1)^0 = 1$$

3. The reverse $x=-1,  y=1$ happens to be false.

$$(-1)^0 = (1)^4$$
$$(1)^0 \neq -1$$